# How to Refresh listview using getview of BaseAdapter on image clickEvent

Tags: java, android

```
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    Teami = (LayoutInflater) contextTeam
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = Teami.inflate(com.yellowflag.activity.R.layout.yf_login3_list_row,
            null);
    TextView txtzmarket = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(com.yellowflag.activity.R.id.txtzmarket);
    TextView txtzname = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(com.yellowflag.activity.R.id.txtzname);
    final ImageView img_nfl_favoriteactive = (ImageView) v
            .findViewById(com.yellowflag.activity.R.id.imgfavoriteactive);
    ImageView nfllist_image = (ImageView) v
            .findViewById(com.yellowflag.activity.R.id.list_image);

    String s = TeamList.get(position).getTeamID();
    String lower = s.toLowerCase();

    int image_id = contextTeam.getResources().getIdentifier(lower + "_25",
            "drawable", contextTeam.getPackageName());
    nfllist_image.setBackgroundResource(image_id);
    txtzmarket.setText(TeamList.get(position).getMarket());
    txtzname.setText(TeamList.get(position).getName());

    if (selected[position] == 1) {
        img_nfl_favoriteactive.setSelected(true);
    }

    img_nfl_favoriteactive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int i = 0; i < TeamList.size(); i++) {
                selected[i] = 0;
            }

            img_nfl_favoriteactive.setSelected(true);
            selected[position] = 1;





        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

I want to refresh listview using img_nfl_favoriteactive which is an image view of my rowview, Clickevent with getview method.
how to refresh this using getview method clickevent using android please help me?
Again, I also want to know that how can i implement the single item selector in this list view.

Comment: Any result, Amit? I'm with the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271608/refresh-listview-in-imagebutton-onclick-inside-getview-off-a-baseadapter

Answer (score 1):

> adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

is used to refresh your adapter thereby refreshing your listview.
Use this where ever you are interested to have

Comment: i have also one BaseAdapter class that contain getView method so adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() how to use in this

Comment: what does that not work mean? Is it not refreshing or you are not able to write the statement over there or any other?

Comment: I would suggest you to create a method where you write the notifyDataSetChanged() and call the method everywhere where you need to refresh the adapter

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() method is not refreshing the listview, if we use that from getView method of BaseAdapter...... I have same issue

Comment: was this resolved? notificyDataSetChanged() from inside getView() not working for me either