# Refresh ListView in ImageButton.onClick inside getView off a BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, imagebutton, listviewitem, baseadapter

I have an activity that is generated by a custom BaseAdapter and look like this:

[image]

This is the `getView` off the custom BaseAdapter:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Visita visita = getItem(position);

    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.visita_item, null); //The ListView Item

    ImageButton btnUp, btnDown;
    btnUp = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.visita_btn_move_up);
    btnDown = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.visita_btn_move_down);

    btnUp = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.visita_btn_move_up);
    if (position != 0) {// First item can't have the button up
        btnUp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_up);
    }

    btnDown = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.visita_btn_move_down);
    if (position != visitas.size() - 1) {// Last item can't have the button down
        btnDown.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_down);
    }

    final DatabaseAdapter adapter = new DatabaseAdapter(context);

    btnUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "Moving UP");

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            valores.put(DatabaseHelper.VISITA_COLS[5], visita.order - 1);
            String where = "ordem=?";
            String[] whereArgs = {String.valueOf(visita.order)};
            Log.d(TAG, "ID: " + adapter.atualizar(valores, where, whereArgs, DatabaseHelper.TB_VISITA));

                  // I should refresh the ListView now
        }
    });

    btnDown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "Movind DOWN");

             //Here i should need the same, update the order in database and after refresh the ListView
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Basically, the `onClick` off `btnUp` and `btnDown` are self explanatory. The order need to be saved in database too because it will be sent after. The update in dastabase works fine, my problem is: How can I refresh the ListView inside his own BaseAdapter?

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685418/how-to-refresh-listview-using-getview-of-baseadapter-on-image-clickevent) question but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `BroadcastReceiver` to refresh the `ListView` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114050/refresh-listview-with-broadcastreceiver)